# OAuth Facebook Login in Phonegap returns InvalidHeader error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, oauth

I'm developing an app using Phonegap and it implements a Facebook login to save some data using the user_id as a reference. I'm using OAuth.io library to implement the login dialog and everything runs smoothly in the web browser and in Android but when I test the app in XCode and I tap the login button the following error appears.

> Cannot find hostname in file:/// from static 
>   code: InvalidHeader 
>   message: Cannot find hostname in file:/// from static

My guess is that it has something to do with phonegap not making an external request since the app is not actually hosted in a domain but running locally... any thoughts?

Comment: Any ideas? It happens the same to me.

Comment: check this one https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap/issues/11

Comment: Hey @Aravinth, I thought of that but I'm sure I'm using the right version, the PhoneGap version of the JS plugin, not the web one. One thing is that I have sent to the plugin makers several e-mails but without response :/...

Comment: Strange because this one says the issue is there in the Android as well

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070242/oauth-io-phonegap-social-login-cannot-find-hostname-in-file/

Comment: It happens both on Android and iOS because is a web based plugin for PhoneGap. I contacted the OAuth.io people like 2 or 3 weeks ago and they have not given me any help. I think I will have to use something else, a custom development like the one found here:

http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using oauth.js library instead of phonegap version
In your main page "index.html" add reference to the correct js file

```
<script src="oauth-phonegap.js"></script>
```

Then follow the instructions [here](https://oauth.io/getting-started?phonegap&None) to build your application

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue using oauth.io. Turns out it was my Ajax prefilter changing the REQUEST to Facebook(it was adding parameters to the header for each request). Wether this is your issue or not, what you need to do is compare a successful REQUEST to Facebook to an unseccussful one, that will show you where things go wrong. Alternativly a blank phonegap app with no extra code other then the required oauth code should work and will be a Good starting point to isolate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Phonegap 2 years before.Though I didn't connect to facebook before,I connected to other website by OAuth.I can show you my solution.

Firstly,you should know how OAuth works.You can read OAuth 2.0 from facebook developer website or other websites.

Secondly,you should know your target:token,uid,expires_time.The most important thing is token.

Thirdly,just do it.In 2010,I solve this problem by using Phonegap Childbrowser plugin(now Phonegap have a inAppBrowser) and a light server.

Why I should use a light server?The server can help me to handle the redirecting in OAuth service and do cache.

Step 1 : I wrote script to connect with my server,and my server connect to OAuth Service(facebook).

Step 2 : OAuth Service(Facebook) do response and redirect to Facebook login page.

Step 3 : After input username and password,OAuth Service(Facebook) will redirect to another url and do a callback with some code or token.

Step 4 : If you get the token,save it and use it to connect OAuth Service(Facebook) if you want.

When I saw "Cannot find hostname in file:/// from static " in your description,I know that maybe you get confuse in OAuth.Now,I suggest you some server side code to handle it and make your OAuth process possible.