# Oauth.io phonegap social login (cannot find hostname in file:///)

Tags: cordova, oauth, oauth-2.0, phonegap-plugins

I have included oauth.js file. I am initializing the oauth using following code

```
OAuth.initialize('public-key');
OAuth.popup('twitter', function(error, result) {
                console.log(result);
                //handle error with error
                //use result.access_token in your API request
                result.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json').done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    alert('Hello ' + data.name)
                })
            });
```

Its properly working in browser but not in device.

I have tried to include following plugin in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="OAuth.io" value="com.phonegap.plugins.oauthio" version="0.1.1"/>
```

But i am getting "this plugin is not supported for phonegap" message at the time of creating the build in `[https://build.phonegap.com/][1]`.

So I have removed that plugin and created the .apk file and executed in device. Its getting following error which is mentioned in screen shot.

[image]

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Please suggest me.....

Comment: Here happens the same. Did you get to solve it?

Comment: I am facing the same hard thing (Pain in the ass) and found this:

http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Will try it. Maybe you can also try it and let me know if it works to you.

Comment: Bit of an old one to drag up - but did you get this working? I get an error now: `This app has a plugin dependency conflict (org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser). Check the plugins tab. `

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out ?
https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap/issues/11

I think you are using the wrong plugin version. The best way to check this is print the result for OAuth.getVersion() and check whether it is the correct version you are using (phone gap version instead of the web version).

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the reference to the oauthio js file from your html (phonegap will inject it)

2) Make sure you have included phonegap.js or cordova.js before everything.

3) Make sure that you are initialising the oauthio after the device ready event has been fired.

> document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){ OAuth.initialize('app_id'); }, false)